# ScrollView Ignore OnTouch while Scrolling?

Tags: android

I have a ScrollView -> Table => TableRow that I dynamically add Rows to, each row has a LinearLayout inside of it that I attach a OnTouchListener to and then when its touched I do something.  At least that was the plan, the problem I am having is that when you scroll in the ScrollView, even while scrolling it fires off these events.  This type of behavior does not occur for the other controls I have in the ScrollView such as Buttons, ImageButtons, EditText

My question is how do I get the LinearLayout to ignore these OnTouch events while the ScrollView is scrolling like the Button and EditText fields do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inside your onTouch event callback add an if statement or case block to that that checks for

`(me.getAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL)` similar to this:

```
else if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL){
                 Log.i(myTag, "Action Cancel");

                 //This means we are scrolling on the list, not trying to press


}
```

It has been a long time since I worked on it, but I know I had to solve this problem at one point, and upon a quick glance just now I think this is what I had to do in order to get it working. It is going to keep receiving callbacks while the list is scrolling, but the action on them should be cancel. So if you set up some sort of if, or switch/case that checks for action_cancel and does nothing when it is true, from the users perspective the onTouch will "ignore" the events that happen while scrolling.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work Tim, the Action only has one value and its Down or Up, it never seems to have Cancel as its value...

Comment: Wow, ok after painfully testing nearly a 100 different ways the way to do this is you HAVE to call setClickable(true) before you will get the Cancel and Move events, otherwise all you get is Down/Up

Comment: I would like to add my experience to this, the touch events come in as Down -> Cancel -> Move, Android automatically cancels the Up event for you if Cancel is called.  If you need to highlight something on down, and then unhighlight and take action in up this is problematic.  I got around this by using a Handler delay in Down of 100 ms, and a Handler delay of 150 ms in Up.  This way absolutely nothing on the UI changes if the user touches these items and scrolls, if they hold over an item you will get Down but no Cancel, to fix that I also unhighlight without a delay.

Comment: @FoamyGuy  Thank you so much ..you saved my Day...+1 vote for u..Thanks again